# Argument 1 missing or nil with replicated storage

Tags: roblox

```
      local Ally = {}
local PhysicsService = game:GetService("PhysicsService")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local PlaceTowerEvent = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Event").PlaceTower
wait(1)

function Ally.Spawn(player,name,cframe)
    local AllyExists = game.ReplicatedStorage.Towers:FindFirstChild(name)
    if AllyExists then
        
        local TowerClone = AllyExists:Clone()
        TowerClone.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = cframe
        TowerClone.Parent = workspace.Allies
        AllyExists.HumanoidRootPart:SetNetworkOwnership(nil)
        
        for i, v in pairs(TowerClone:GetChildren()) do
            if v:IsA("BasePart") then
                v.CollisionGroup = "Ally"
            end
        end
    else
        warn("Tower does not exist")
    end
end

wait(1)
PlaceTowerEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(Ally.Spawn)
return Ally
```

> on line `ReplicatedStorage.Towers:FindFirstChild(name)`, it says `argument 1 missing or nil`. i've tried looking through my other scripts and re - watching the tutorial but everything seems fine. I have no clue on how to solve this so please help!

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely that you're not sending the data from the client to the server properly. As it might return the parameters 'name' and 'cframe' nil.

An example where it would reproduce your issue;
Client:

```lua
remoteEvent:FireServer()
remoteEvent:FireServer(nil, nil)
```

Server:

```lua
remoteEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, param1, param2)
    print(param1, param2) -- nil, both times
end)
```

You could check what the client sends through the remote to the server
It should result in the parameters being sent, being nil or the objects that you're sending are mutable and only exist on the client, meaning the server doesn't have a reference to that client-only object.

To solve you should just diagnose what the parameters are on the client.

Comment: I don't know what diagnose what the parameters are on the client means sorry

Comment: print what the parameters say righit before doing fireserver

Comment: I done that and it says "My player name,nil nil" But I don't know what to do to fix it

Comment: the variables behind name and cframe on the client need to be populated with values, in this case name and cframe